# JS getting undefined from the function but the server is returning a valid JSON

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

This is the function i am using to get the preferred movie list from the mongodb.

```
function PreferedMovieData() {
    var init_var = {method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'no-cors',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  'http://127.0.0.1:5001',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({"page_no": 1})
                };
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5001/prefered/movies_list", init_var).then(response => {
        return response.text();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    });
}
PreferedMovieData();
```

i am getting the response back as **undefined**

Comment: does it log undefined if you `return response.json()` as well? Also you may be wanting to do a GET instead of a POST

Comment: Can you explain why you are using the `no-cors` mode? 99% of the time that mode is completely useless because all it does is not send the `Origin` header

Comment: @Edon nope. when i tried with json() i am getting an error Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @slebetman when i remove mode i am facing following error. Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/prefered/movies_list' from origin 'chrome://new-tab-page' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: is this plain javascript application or you are using node.js?

Comment: bcoz as far as i know *fetch API is not available out of the box for NodeJS applications*  use the node-fetch package or other similar API.

Comment: @Arunachalam Even **with** mode your broser will still be blocking by CORS policy. Only perhaps it will not display an error. Your real problem is that your request is being blocked by CORS. Fix it at the server. You **CANNOT** fix it on the browser as this is designed intentionally like this

Answer (score 1):

Change your fetch api in this way:

```js
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5001/prefered/movies_list", init_var).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: this didn't work

Comment: Instead of passing `init_var` into the `fetch` function, pass the whole JSON which is previously assigned to `init_var`.

Comment: i have tried it logs **undefined**

Comment: response.text() logs **undefined**.  response.json() logs the error VM879:13 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at <anonymous>:13:24